# Sorting the date string in the DD-MM-yyyy format using lodash

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lodash

have a following function:

```
listOfTransactions.map(({ tdate='', out='', in='' }) => {

return  {
  date: '10 Feb 2022',
  out: 'AAA
  in: 'BBB'
}
})
```

// Here multiple objects will be returned from here, but the format of the date will be like this only. Now, I need to sort this in a descending order , so I tried

```
_.sortBy(   listOfTransactions.map(({ tdate='', out='', in='' }) => {
    
    return  {
      date: '10 Feb 2022',
      out: 'AAA
      in: 'BBB'
    }
    })  , 'date')
```

But this is not working .So, any suggestions/ help how do I sort this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

According to [lodash docs](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#sortBy) you need to return the value want to sort by. Since it is specifically dates, you first need to convert them to `Date` objects.

```
_.sortBy(listOfTransactions, (transaction) => new Date(transaction.date))
```

I believe this should return what you need.